# can we create a twbx file from twb file - Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to get a twbx file from twb file from commandline(tabcmd).
I have tried http://community.tableau.com/thread/135045.
The problem with the above mentioned site is that it requires data extract(.tde) file to be uploaded and this .tde file cannot be generated by using tabcmd.

How can i complete the above mentioned task using tabcmd.
OR is there any better way to transform twb -> twbx file.

Comment: Does the workbook use any kind of flat file (that was included when publishing to Server), or an extract?

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear from your description, so I'll have to cover both scenarios:

1. If your workbook was published with an extracted data source (an "embedded" data source), then it is possible to download a packaged workbook using tabcmd.
2. If your workbook is using a published extract data source, then downloading the workbook with tabcmd (or any other means) will not automatically download the published extract. Even if you were to download the data source XML file, you still wouldn't have the extract - getting the extract itself would require opening the data source in Tableau Desktop, logging on to Tableau Server and then creating a local copy

Since it's likely that you're dealing with scenario 2, then I would suggest that you contact Tableau Support as they can file a feature/enhancement request for you

Comment: Thanks for your insights.
Here my scenario is similar to point 2.However i want (.twb) to (.twbx) without publishing any report.
Since it is understood from your reply that there is no special feature ,can you suggest any hacks to do it?
"Creating a local copy after logging in tableau server " can this step be done in tabcmd(i searched but couldn't find)

Comment: I don't fully understand the requirement. If the workbook isn't being published, then tabcmd is of no use since that only interacts with Tableau Server.

As far as I know, creating a local copy of a published data source can only be done using Tableau Desktop. I would reiterate my suggestion of contacting Tableau Support for further assistance in creating a feature request, giving a detailed explanation of your specific business case.